# IPA language with Visual studio (Cordova)

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I have a problem when I try to set the language of the IPA.
My App is in French but only English is added in the generated IPA. I do not kwnow how to change this.
I use visual studio with Cordova tools.

I have tried to add a locales folder but it changes nothing...

Do you have an idea of what I need to do in order to add French to the IPA?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which version of Cordova tools are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to specify that in your **Info.plist** file. You are able to supply a custom **Info.plist** with your build.

In your **.plist** file you will then be able to specify the localization as follows:

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>English</string>
    <string>French</string>
</array>
```

To find out more adding custom configuration files, please have a look at MSDN's [Platform-specific configuration files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757053.aspx#NativeConfig)

Comment: I try to override the info.plist. i add the file in res/native/ios/config.xml with the content of info.plist. But the file appName-info.plist is not override in the mac in folder remoteBuild.

Comment: Ok, just to be clear, you are creating a file and naming it **<display name from config.xml>**-Info.plist, and then placing that file in res/native/ios/<display name from config.xml>/.

So if your app name is myApp, the path will be: res/native/ios/myApp/myApp-Info.plist.  

Lastly, just to make sure, you are using the latest version of Cordova tools for Visual Studio?

Comment: It works ! The doc is not easy to understand... Thanks for your help